# Grub waiting for input Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 fine, but Grub is waiting for Enter..? Why?

/etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Comment: Any particular reason there is a shell command in GRUB's config...?

Answer (score 1):

"GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0"

- This is why you have to press enter for GRUB to execute; it is telling GRUB to stay on screen indefinitely until given physical keyboard command.
- Either edit the GRUB file manually
- Or if your not comfortable working from the terminal, check out this tutorial to install [Grub2 Customizer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10340183#post10340183) to configure GRUB though a gui.